# How to listen to every state change in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, queue

I have an example component:

```
export default function MyPlugin() {
  const { component: Plugin, instance } = useMyPlugin()
  const [lastConfigUpdate, setLastConfigUpdate] = useState<Record<string, string>>({
    config: "config-update-1",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setLastConfigUpdate({ config2: "config-update-2" });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLastConfigUpdate({ config3: "config-update-3" });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLastConfigUpdate({ config4: "config-update-4" });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // i need this section to catch all my setLastConfigUpdate
    // otherwise some configuration will not be passed to the my plugin
    console.log("my plugin will update config using " + JSON.stringify(lastConfigUpdate));
    instance.load(lastConfigUpdate)
  }, [lastConfigUpdate]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Plugin/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

React optimizes the way state is updated so I only see a log for "config-update-4" and consequently I only instance.load({ config4: "config-update-4" }).

Is it possible to have the last useEffect to actually log all state updates?

The final effect I would like to get is to push into the lastConfigUpdate queue and pull it to apply the config updates.

Is there a better data structure I can use?

Comment: Why don't you use a useEffect without second param ?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently overwriting the state. instead, you should update it in a way that accumulates changes. Please consider using the functional form of the state updater within each of your useEffect blocks.

here is a small example,

```
useEffect(() => {
  setLastConfigUpdate((prevConfig) => {
    return {
      ...prevConfig,
      config2: "config-update-2"
    };
  });
}, []);
```